# Calendar using Knockout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, calendar

I have written some code that creates a week at a glance calendar view using jquery that is also responsive, using bootstrap. I'm not so sure this is that best was to go about this though. I'm not sure that this is the best implementation. Would it be better to use Knockout?

In the future I will implement client created events that should show up on the calendar. I am not sure how to go about this? My mess of appending with jquery just seems wrong to me even though it works.

[Here's a link to jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/jtholla2/ezU96/)

Here's that mess of jquery I was talking about.

```
$('<li>').attr('class', (events[today.format('D')][0] == null ? 'calendar-day' : 'calendar-day-event')).append(
$('<div>').attr('class', 'date').append(
$('<span>').attr('class', 'day').append(
today.format('dddd')).append(", ")).append(
$('<span>').attr('class', 'month').append(
today.format('MMMM')).append(" ")).append(
today.format('D')).append(
$('<a>').attr('href', events[today.format('D')][5]).attr('class', 'event-info').append(
$('<div>').attr('class', 'event-name').append(
events[today.format('D')][4])).append(
$('<div>').attr('class', 'event-time').append(
events[today.format('D')][2])).append(
$('<div>').attr('class', 'location').append(
events[today.format('D')][3])))));
```

Comment: Might be worth having a look at https://facebook.github.io/react/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would the apprehension be due to unfamiliarity with `knockout`? Even though that eyesore "works" it is indeed horrendous. Take for instance the same logic in knockout.

**Html**

```
 <ul class="days" id="days" data-bind='foreach: weekdays'>
    <li data-bind='css: hasEvent() ? "calendar-day-event" : "calendar-day"'>
       <div class='date'> 
          <span class='day' data-bind='text: day() + ","'></span>
           <span class='month' data-bind='text: month'></span>
           <span data-bind='text: date'></span>
           <!--ko foreach:events-->
               <a data-bind='attr:{href: details}'>
                  <div data-bind='text: description'></div>
                  <div data-bind='text: time'></div>
                  <div data-bind='text: location'></div>
                </a>
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
     </li>
  </ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
var Day = function (moment, events) {

 var obj = {
  day : ko.observable(moment.format('dddd')),
  month : ko.observable(moment.format('MMM')),
  date : ko.observable(moment.format('D')),
  events : ko.observableArray([]) 
 }

 //if any additional manipulation required...otherwise just use obj.events:ko.observableArray(events)
 $.each(events, function (index, value) {
    obj.events.push(value)
 })
 obj.hasEvent = ko.computed(function () {
    return obj.events().length > 0
 })
 return obj;
}

/*snippet*/

events[24] = [{
  month: "May",
  day: "24",
  time: "3:00 pm - 5:00 pm",
  location: "My house",
  description: "Barbecue for the weekend",
  details: "EventDetail.html"
}];


/*2 pieces together*/
vm.weekdays.push(new Day(today, events[today.format('D')]));
```

At a glance the code "tells" you what it is doing. You are not left to rely on some source highlighting to tell you where the multiple appearances of `.append` begin and end. Granted that could be alleviated by some source formatting, but that would be just a band-aid. From a maintenance standpoint, 6-months from now I'd much rather have to look at the knockout than that jQuery.

See [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/4LRJF/) for full implementation.

---

I have [forked the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/rvCX4/) and provided a rough generalization of the ability to add an event. Clicking the date numeral will launch the modal.

A few things to consider:

- If you attempt to `ko.applyBindings` on an element more than once you'll get an error. You'll notice I use `ko.cleanNode` to address that.
- Since the `template` will have bound html in it, I use `.empty()` to get rid of it once I'm done. Hence the need to reload `$('#dialog-container')`'s html.
- If you don't `.splice` the events you would be modifying the existing event array directly which would prevent you from having the ability to revert/ignore changes in the dialog.

Comment: Yeah, my god thats so much easier to understand. I don't have a great understanding of knockout and haven't used it before. Seeing your example shows a great example of how I could use it. Am I correct in saying that knockout will make creating events a bit easier as well?

Comment: Added a forked fiddle to show a rough example of the requirements for an "Add" feature.